# NSUnknownKeyException setValue:forUndefinedKey:

Tags: iphone, ios5, uitableview, nsexception

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException',
>   reason: '[ setValue:forUndefinedKey:]:
>   this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key
>   buttonOfFirstView.'

Why do I get this error? I am trying to make a table cell though XIB. After I add this code it throws the above exception.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"MyCell";

    MyTableViewCell *cell = (MyTableViewCell*) [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    if (cell == nil) {

        NSArray *arrayCellXib = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"MyTableViewCell" 
                                                              owner:self 
                                                            options:nil];

....
} 
.....

return cell;
}
```

How to resolve it?

Comment: wat is your buttonOfFirstView.?

Comment: a button inside table cell 
IBOutlet UIButton buttonOfFirstView;

Comment: check if it is connected properly

Comment: I solved it, changed file owner to NSObject an problem has been solved. Why I dont know. But it is running fine.

Answer (score 49, accepted):

Check your references of your outlets in your XIB, one of them is probably referencing a property (buttonOfFirstView) that does not exist anymore

Answer (score 2):

Set File's Owner class to `NSObject` and set `UITableViewCell` class to your custom class in XIB. It will solve the issue.

Answer (score 1):

This is exactly an issue related to the key buttonOfFirstView in your case.If it is a button it may be connected wrongly in any of your xibs

Comment: I didn't get u, please explain more

Comment: If it is not working,just rename your button.And  connect it properly.

Comment: not work for me, same exceptions

Comment: have u synthesized ur button?

Comment: u shud import MyTableViewCell in ur table view

Comment: refer this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2242517/nsunknownkeyexception-exception-raised-applicaton-crashes

Answer (score 0):

Quit the iOS simulator. Make sure you save the project and then quit xCode and restart and everything will be fine. I did that and it worked for me. that's if everything else is hooked up correctly.

Answer (score 0):

you need to clean your project: go to Product -> Clean

this works for me