# i did not understand what is this error

Tags: swift, xcode

```
2015-06-03 17:16:15.705 PSM-InPatient[10744:799454] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException', reason: '[<PSM_InPatient.DocLoginViewController 0x7fbf3bc75990> setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key docPassword.'
*** First throw call stack:
(
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x0000000105b37f35 __exceptionPreprocess + 165
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x000000010767bbb7 objc_exception_throw + 45
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x0000000105b37b79 -[NSException raise] + 9
    3   Foundation                          0x0000000105f4f7b3 -[NSObject(NSKeyValueCoding) setValue:forKey:] + 259
    4   CoreFoundation                      0x0000000105a81e80 -[NSArray makeObjectsPerformSelector:] + 224
    5   UIKit                               0x0000000106688c7d -[UINib instantiateWithOwner:options:] + 1506
    6   UIKit                               0x00000001064e7f98 -[UIViewController _loadViewFromNibNamed:bundle:] + 242
    7   UIKit                               0x00000001064e8588 -[UIViewController loadView] + 109
    8   UIKit                               0x00000001064e87f9 -[UIViewController loadViewIfRequired] + 75
    9   UIKit                               0x00000001064e8c8e -[UIViewController view] + 27
    10  UIKit                               0x0000000106a8a41e -[_UIFullscreenPresentationController _setPresentedViewController:] + 65
    11  UIKit                               0x00000001064c4429 -[UIPresentationController initWithPresentedViewController:presentingViewController:] + 105
    12  UIKit                               0x00000001064f4a41 -[UIViewController _presentViewController:withAnimationController:completion:] + 1746
    13  UIKit                               0x00000001064f6d81 __62-[UIViewController presentViewController:animated:completion:]_block_invoke + 132
    14  UIKit                               0x00000001064f6ca5 -[UIViewController presentViewController:animated:completion:] + 229
    15  UIKit                               0x00000001063c48be -[UIApplication sendAction:to:from:forEvent:] + 75
    16  UIKit                               0x00000001064cb410 -[UIControl _sendActionsForEvents:withEvent:] + 467
    17  UIKit                               0x00000001064ca7df -[UIControl touchesEnded:withEvent:] + 522
    18  UIKit                               0x000000010640a308 -[UIWindow _sendTouchesForEvent:] + 735
    19  UIKit                               0x000000010640ac33 -[UIWindow sendEvent:] + 683
    20  UIKit                               0x00000001063d79b1 -[UIApplication sendEvent:] + 246
    21  UIKit                               0x00000001063e4a7d _UIApplicationHandleEventFromQueueEvent + 17370
    22  UIKit                               0x00000001063c0103 _UIApplicationHandleEventQueue + 1961
    23  CoreFoundation                      0x0000000105a6d551 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 17
    24  CoreFoundation                      0x0000000105a6341d __CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 269
    25  CoreFoundation                      0x0000000105a62a54 __CFRunLoopRun + 868
    26  CoreFoundation                      0x0000000105a62486 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 470
    27  GraphicsServices                    0x0000000109c2e9f0 GSEventRunModal + 161
    28  UIKit                               0x00000001063c3420 UIApplicationMain + 1282
    29  PSM-InPatient                       0x00000001055a33de top_level_code + 78
    30  PSM-InPatient                       0x00000001055a341a main + 42
    31  libdyld.dylib                       0x0000000107e55145 start + 1
)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
```

Comment: Did you search for `NSUnknownKeyException` answers ?

Comment: this error is a simple exception. which part of your code throws it?

Comment: not yet. i am just using Xcode n still not really understand. i will search then. Tq

Comment: possible duplicate of [NSUnknownKeyException setValue:forUndefinedKey:](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10828608/nsunknownkeyexception-setvalueforundefinedkey)

Comment: possible duplicate of [What does this mean? "'NSUnknownKeyException', reason: ... This class is not key value coding-compliant for the key X"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3088059/what-does-this-mean-nsunknownkeyexception-reason-this-class-is-not-key)

Answer (score 1):

You have an outlet that doesn't exists anymore. Check the connections inspector for lost connections.

Comment: can i know where to check the connections?  :'(

Comment: Select your View and click the top right button of the right panel (small right arrow, connections inspector).

Answer (score 0):

Your error is `Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException', reason: '[ setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key docPassword`.

Usually this means that the .xib file (or storyboard) for your viewController contains an outlet (`docPassword` in your case) that isn't in your code. You should either add the property in your code or remove the outlet entirely in interface builder.

Comment: do you mean redo back the outlets?

Comment: Either reconnect/recreate the outlets or remove them, yes.